# Java 2D Game engine for tile-based Game

Tags: java, frameworks, 2d

Can anyone recommend a good Java game engine for developing simple tile-based games? 
I'm looking for an engine that will allow me to build maps using something like Tiled  www.mapeditor.org

Slick is exactly what I'm looking for,  slick.cokeandcode.com but I can't get it working on Vista-64.  The best I can manage is:Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform (and this after downloading the latest LWJGL version).

Can anyone suggest something similar that will run on 64-bit vista?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend purchasing the book "Developing Games in Java" by David Brackeen, it includes a tile-based game framework which seems excellent (I haven't implemented anything with it yet though).

[Link to amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1592730051)

You could also download the code without getting the book, but I'd recommend the book.

Comment: Looks like a great book! I'll check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

checkout this http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/

Answer (score 3):

[PulpCore](http://www.interactivepulp.com/pulpcore/) is utterly cool, supports tiling, but uses a software renderer and cannot run as a desktop application. Its development paradigm is very, very similar to Flash, except it has the benefit of being Java ;).

[Slick](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) also supports tiling, is hardware accelerated (OpenGL via LWJGL), and can run as applet, desktop or webstart (JNLP), but on the downside it's not nearly as clean as Pulpcore in terms of ease-of-coding.

If you need serious onscreen action (as in action/arcade) then go Slick, otherwise I recommend PulpCore. If I didn't need hardware support for my game, I'd be on PulpCore in a second.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Java Game Engines, but your *"Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform"* problem can be solved by uninstalling the 64-bit version of Java, and installing the 32-bit version instead. (It may be possible to have both 32-bit and 64-bit versions running in parallel, but if you're not doing 64-bit programming, then you're probably better off just sticking with the one version).

The 32-bit version is the version for "Windows", rather than "Windows x64". Note that the 32-bit version of Java will live in *Program Files (x86)* rather than *Program Files* - you may need to update some paths if you've already configured Slick and/or an IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Just to address your secondary issue, you can run Slick on a 64 bit architecture without needing to uninstall 64-bit java...

All you need to do is grab the latest [LWGJL jar](http://lwjgl.org/download.php) file and import it into your project.  Then you need to load the naitive libraries (including the win64 dll) from the LWGJL jar.  This will allow you to run Slick2D in Win64 without messing around with your Java version.

Answer (score 2):

There's Slick, JGame, GLib (very new, rather buggy), and XNA (C#, similar to Java). Take your pick.

-Slick: http://goo.gl/CXsp
-JGame: http://goo.gl/Kdjrj
-GLib: http://goo.gl/LGFAw
-XNA: http://goo.gl/n4X1A

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx is brilliant and includes support for TMX such as tiled. https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/
You can also combine this with box2d fairly easily.