# JScrollPane for Java 2d top-down game

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, ram

Would it be bad for me to run a Java 2d top-down game with a JScrollPane? Reading through the Java Docs, it is possible. Resetting the JScrollBar position after moving the player... I just want to know how bad that would be for the RAM... My goal for this game is to be VERY good on RAM

Comment: Yes it is *possible*. No you probably shouldn't do it.

Comment: Try looking into drawing your own component. You don't want a player to be able to use a scroll pane to scroll over your entire map.

Comment: @Quirliom: the JScrollPane can be used with the scrollbars hidden, preventing the user from manually changing the scroll position. This is not an issue at all.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903760/java-2d-game-engine-for-tile-based-game